# Why nvidia card get poweroff after logout on a multiseat arch system?

Tags: ubuntu, arch-linux, multiseat

Recently I moved to arch Linux from Ubuntu 21.04. I am using a multi seat option for Ubuntu as well as archlinux. When I am using Ubuntu linux, my seat1 can logout without any problem. But in arch Linux when I logout from seat1 my NVIDIA card get powered-off. It seems like I am missing some sort of package or configuration that Ubuntu give me out-of-box. Pls highlight what I am missing and why this happening?

Comment: Probably because Nvidia works in runlevel 4-5 ? Debian (→Ubuntu) is always 2-5 .  https://wiki.debian.org/RunLevel#:~:text=The%20runlevel%20is%20a%20digit,runlevels%20(0%2D6). ...  Logout from Arch may switch to runlevel 3 ?

Comment: This post is fairly light on the details: what versions of the NVIDIA drivers are you using? What documentation have you looked at to try and diagnose the problem? Does the same thing happen when a different seat number logs out of the system?